# How to show grid layout instead of list view in Wordpress admin area

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, posts

I need grid view layout instead of simple list view layout in Wordpress posts
like we use bootstrap columns.
Here is a screenshot of current Wordpress posts:

[image: here is a current screenshot of wp admin posts1]

But I don't want this layout I want grid system here. Currently Wordpress is
using tables and I need grids here we can use div.
Do you know any plugins which does so?
I found one but its premium plugin in codecanyon
http://codecanyon.net/item/admin-post-grid/11405282

Comment: First update your wordpress  to v4.3 !

Comment: I have updated it to latest one. do you find any solution to my problem